# MAMP links not found

Tags: mamp

Im using mamp on osx 10.8.

On the site I am developing I get the error:

```
Not Found

The requested URL /test was not found on this server.
```

There is nothing wrong with the site - as it's a copy from my main computer.

I think there is something wrong with the mamp set up on my laptop.

The homepage of my site works fine, it's just links to other parts of the site that are broken.

Any ideas?

Comment: Is `/test` a directory or do you have some url rewriting/routing going on?

Comment: url rewritting is in place

Answer (score 1):

```
AllowOverride All
```

This did the trick.

Comment: Where did you set this?